# ESP8266 - Live Update Server, without refresh?

Tags: arduino, webserver, client, wifi, esp8266

I have came across the nice and little [ESP8266](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/overview)

[image: ESP8266-HUZZAH]

and I have went through the examples and got it run on my home's WiFI network as a server and display a counter on each page refresh. I used the [Arduino IDE](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/using-arduino-ide) with the libraries for the ESP8266

Is it possible (and if yes, how?) to display live updates without refreshing the page? For example, if I want to display a live counter, clock, or buffer images/video?

Comment: This is a fairly old question, but none of the answers seem to talk about [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). I'm not sure what kind of support exists for the ESP8266, but let it be known that they are not a simple undertaking

Comment: It is an old question, but as far as I remember using the ESP8266 - it was simple, and not that complex. Not sure about your background and prior experience, but it is not an off the shelf item.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of the technology you use to view the page. I guess you're serving HTML? Without a new request there will be no update. But there are multiple ways you can tell the browser to re request the page:

- HTML [meta refresh](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html)
- JavaScript embedded in the HTML page which reloads the whole page: [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)
- JavaScript embedded in the HTML which is triggered by a [timer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), reads the response of a [AJAX request](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) and modifies the HTML page

Either way, the solution is not related to the ESP8266.

Comment: So how can the ESP8266 do any of those?

Comment: Do you want your ESP8266 to act as a server or a client? The question text sounded like 'server'. But your comment suggests that you want it to be a client. Please add details to your question in which context you want to use the SoC and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want it to be a server. Essentially connect it to a mcu and make it show live data from the mcu without the need to refresh.

Comment: There will always be the need for a refresh. This is how http works. But you can make the browser execute the refresh automatically. The ESP8266 only has to serve the html code containing the refresh code. The refresh is completely ESP8266 unrelated.